# Egit fails during clone with read time out error

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have a repository I am trying to clone with EGit. It fails with the error as below. But if I try the same with terminal git clone it works. I would have used the workaround, but apparently I cant use the git repo cloned from the command line in eclipse. When I try to import the local repo it imports it, but none of the projects display any options under the Team right click context menu.

Could someone tell me why the read is timing out.. And why when I add an existing local repo no options are displayed under the right click Team menu.

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of fetch command
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CloneOperation.run(CloneOperation.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.executeCloneOperation(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.access$2(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard$6.run(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Read timed out
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObjects(FetchProcess.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:129)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Read timed out
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.readTimedOut(TimeoutInputStream.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.read(TimeoutInputStream.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.IO.readFully(IO.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readLength(PacketLineIn.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SideBandInputStream.needDataPacket(SideBandInputStream.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SideBandInputStream.read(SideBandInputStream.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.fill(PackParser.java:1122)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.readPackHeader(PackParser.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryPackParser.parse(ObjectDirectoryPackParser.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.receivePack(BasePackFetchConnection.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:284)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get team options:

1. import project from EGit
2. right click on project -> Team -> Share Project...
3. select Git, Next
4. tick "use or create repository in parent folder of project", Finish

You should now have team options enabled in your project

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and I solved with these steps:

- Navigate to Eclpse>Preferences>General>Network Connections>SSH2
- In General tab there were 2 private keys id_dsa and id_rsa
- I removed id_rsa and only id_dsa is left

Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Pls be sure you configed correct ssh rsa or dsa public key in EGIT eclipse preferences tab. In additional for this, user.name and user.email is essential if your project is based on the gerrit.

Br,
Tim